# android WebView overflow:auto trigger SwipeRefreshLayout on scroll up

Tags: android, webview, scroll, overflow, swiperefreshlayout

When you load in WebView content with overflow:auto and it is surrounded with SwipeRefreshLayout, scroll down is working good, but scroll up triggers onRefresh of SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webview"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    browser = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.loadUrl("https://odatv.com/mob.php"); //this is the url where the problem appears
}
```

In [this site](https://odatv.com/mob.php) the problem appears only in mobile phones, in tablets it is working ok.
[Video demonstration](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15w0SjZ_0ErESjknGnpx-wE2MP620Nxkl) 
I extend WebView to check scroll position but onScrollChanged in not called and onOverScrolled is called only on scroll horizontal.

How to make SwipeRefreshLayout work correctly in this case?

Comment: Have same problem, found any solution?